# Seeking References on the History of Scientific Dissemination

Tags: reference-request, popularizatio, dissemination, publicawareness

recently read a book on the history of science by academic Tatiana Roque. In it, she discusses how, during the Enlightenment, scientific dissemination was a fundamental assumption. Roque writes that knowledge inherently aimed to reach a broad audience, beyond the restricted circles of the Republic of Letters. This desire to engage the public was integral to knowledge production. She further notes the Encyclopedia's distribution through unofficial means, the widespread circulation of selected articles in anonymous brochures, and the strategic role of science popularization in garnering trust in new ideals.

One example she cites is the Great Exhibition of 1851 in London, inaugurated by Queen Victoria, showcasing the era's progress. She also mentions the formation of the British Association for the Advancement of Science in 1831, with the aim of promoting and disseminating scientific knowledge. In the latter half of the 19th century, museums and exhibitions proliferated, maintaining the popularity of science among the expanding and decentralizing middle class. Victorian era 'conversaziones' combined scientific knowledge, technological skill, and appreciation for art and fashion, fostering a new visual culture and participatory public understanding of science.

Considering these historical insights into the critical role of scientific dissemination, I'm looking for references (such as books) that specifically address the history of scientific dissemination. Can anyone recommend comprehensive sources on this topic?

Comment: Not my area of expertise. Is this the kind of book you might be interested in? Faidra Papanelopoulou, Agustí Nieto-Galan, and Enrique Perdiguero (eds.), *Popularizing Science and Technology in the European Periphery, 1800-2000.* Ashgate Publishing 2009, ca. 300 pp.

Comment: Peter J. Bowler, *Science for All: The Popularization of Science in Early Twentieth-Century Britain.* University of Chicago Press 2009, ca. 350 pp. "Recent scholarship has revealed that pioneering Victorian scientists endeavored through voluminous writing to raise public interest in science and its implications. But it has generally been assumed that once science became a profession around the turn of the century, this new generation of scientists turned its collective back on public outreach. Science for All debunks this apocryphal notion."